# Django image uploading error, "This field is required', "no files chosen"

Tags: django, django-models, file-upload, django-forms, django-templates

I was working on a django project. I made a userprofiles app to manage(create, update) user's profile in my website, but it is not working properly. I am getting 'This field is required' &
'no file chosen' while making profile as a user and if I do blank=True in models profile_picture user pictures are not saving in the media url.
I have tried so many tips from stackoverflow but they are not working.
here is my code:

```
# settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('media'))

# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
import uuid


class UserProfile(models.Model):
   author = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
   occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   hobbies = models.TextField(blank=True)
   date_of_birth = models.TimeField()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.author.username + ("'s profile")

# views.py
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class SignUpView(CreateView):
   form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
   template_name = "registration/signup.html"
   success_url = reverse_lazy("profile_create")

# project-level urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("profile/", include("userprofiles.urls")),
    path("", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name="home"),
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# app-level urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProfileCreateView

urlpatterns = [
     path("create/", ProfileCreateView.as_view(), name="profile_create")
 ]


# profile_create.html
 {% extends 'base.html' %}

 {% block title %}Create Your Profile{% endblock title %}

 {% block content %}

 <h2>Create Your Profile</h2>
 <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit">Create my profile</button>
 </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

tell me what is the problem with it, I am stucked out of it, Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you missed **enctype** in html form,

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads),

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method
> was POST, at least one file field was actually posted, and the 
> that posted the request has the attribute
> enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

HTML form should be,

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit">Create my profile</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: It is working, Thanks a lot